# Are deep nested HTML tags bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, html, markup

When I build complex design's markup, I can create deep level of nesting `div`'s (15-20 nesting level). If it is impact bad on SEO?

Comment: I don't think so even if more your page is quickly read by bots, more it is good for SEO.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple nested `div`'s will not affect SEO. As long as the crawlers can navigate your website and encounter unique and valuable content you should be fine.

Comment: I agree. Your HTML structure has no impact on SEO.   There are only a few tags like `<title>` to which Google actually pays any special attention.   Now that Googlebot is rendering pages, even using `<h1>` and `<b>` tags is not needed for SEO because Google sees which text is prominent once it is rendered regardless of what tags are used.